# Making a heapmap with p values after pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, heatmap, pairwise

I'm running multiple pairwise comparisons on grouped factors and I would like to represent the resulting p-values with a heatmap.

This is a small example of what my dataset looks like, but in reality, it is much more complicated.
My factors are site (2 levels) and organisms (3 levels).

```
site = c("SITE1","SITE1","SITE1","SITE1","SITE1","SITE1",
          "SITE1","SITE1","SITE1","SITE2","SITE2","SITE2",
          "SITE2","SITE2","SITE2","SITE2","SITE2","SITE2")
organism = c("Insects","Insects","Insects","Mammals","Mammals",
          "Mammals","Reptiles","Reptiles","Reptiles","Insects",
          "Insects","Insects","Mammals","Mammals","Mammals",
          "Reptiles","Reptiles","Reptiles")
variable = c(5,6,7,12,13,14,1,2,3,7,8,9,22,24,25,11,12,14)


data = data.frame(site, organism, variable)
head(data)

  site organism variable
1 SITE1  Insects        5
2 SITE1  Insects        6
3 SITE1  Insects        7
4 SITE1  Mammals       12
5 SITE1  Mammals       13
6 SITE1  Mammals       14
```

And this is how I'm computing the pairwise tests between pairs of organisms at each individual site:

```
data %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  t_test(variable ~ organism)

   site      .y.  group1   group2 n1 n2  statistic       df        p    p.adj p.adj.signif
1 SITE1 variable Insects  Mammals  3  3  -8.573214 4.000000 0.001000 0.002000           **
2 SITE1 variable Insects Reptiles  3  3   4.898979 4.000000 0.008000 0.008000           **
3 SITE1 variable Mammals Reptiles  3  3  13.472194 4.000000 0.000176 0.000528          ***
4 SITE2 variable Insects  Mammals  3  3 -14.862705 3.448276 0.000300 0.000900          ***
5 SITE2 variable Insects Reptiles  3  3  -4.110961 3.448276 0.020000 0.020000            *
6 SITE2 variable Mammals Reptiles  3  3   9.086882 4.000000 0.000813 0.002000           **
```

I would like to organise my data in a way that I can make a heatmap that would look similar to this:

[image]

I think the function `pwpm` from package `emmeans` does something similar, but it only works for emmeans. I was not able to find anything else.

Furthermore, it would be great if could also subdivide the p.values in p<0.05, p<0.01, p<0.001 for another heatmap so the significance is easier to see.

Could someone help me with this? I've been looking for hours without finding a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via `ggplot2` and facetting. As your data is already in a tidy data format a basic heat map could be achieved via `geom_tile` + `facet_wrap`. The rest is styling, like adding the p-values via `geom_text`, setting the colors via `scale_fill_gradient` or some additional data wrangling using e.g. `tidyr::complete` to add the "missing" group categories.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  t_test(variable ~ organism) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(group1 = unique(data$organism), group2 = unique(data$organism), site = unique(data$site))

ggplot(d, aes(group2, rev(group1), fill = p)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::number(p, accuracy = 1e-6))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", na.value = NA) +
  facet_wrap(~site, ncol = 1)
#> Warning: Removed 12 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]